# linker error of clang on mingw32

Tags: mingw32

I am new for clang and llvm and this mailing forum. I am trying build cland on my windows xp 32 bit system using "cland binaries for mingw32 version 2.9" and "llvm binaries for mingw32 version 2.9". I follow following steps:

1. download mingw in directory (C:/MinGW)
2. download "clang2.9 binaries for mingw32" and "llvm-2.9 binaries for mingw32"
3. extract both in the same directory of mingw (C:/MinGW)
4. set path C:/MinGW/bin to PATH environment.
   Then I write one simple code

   #include
     int main()
      {
          printf("hello world\n");
       return 0;
      }

then compile code

clang hello.cpp -o hello.exe
it compiles fine
but when I tried to execute it
   clang hello.exe
it gives following error

***********************ERROR*****************************
hello.exe:crt1.c:(.text+0x280): multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x280): firs
t defined here
hello.exe:crt1.c:(.text+0x2a0): multiple definition of`WinMainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2a0): firs
t defined here
hello.exe:crt1.c:(.text+0x2c0): multiple definition of `atexit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2c0): firs
t defined here
hello.exe:crt1.c:(.text+0x2d0): multiple definition of`*onexit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2d0): firs
t defined here
hello.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2e0): multiple definition of `__gcc_regist
er_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0):
 first defined here
hello.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x36c): multiple definition of`*_gcc_deregi
ster_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x8c)
: first defined here
hello.exe:crt1.c:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `_argc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.bss+0x4): first d
efined here
hello.exe:crt1.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of`_argv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.bss+0x0): first d
efined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x85)
: undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
clang: error:
      linker
      (via
      gcc)
      command
      failed
      with
      exit
      code
      1
      (use
      -v
      to
      see
      invocation)
*****************************************************]
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to how you can compile Clang from sources on Windows, the article talks about Objective-C and Clang on Windows you can safely ignore that and use the technique described to build Clang. The resulting compiler will compile your C++ code with no problem. Alternatively you can download the author's compiled Clang 3.1:

http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/03/21/clang-objective-c-windows/